# Нужно ли учить Java для создания игр для Android?

Tags: java, android, unity3d, разработка-игр

Хочу делать игры для Android, для этих целей выбрал Unity3d.
Собственно вопрос: нужно ли будет изучать Java или какие то нюансы именно Android платформы?

Comment: Нет, java не надо знать. Код пишется на c# или javascript, потом просто все компилиться в apk средствами юнити

Answer (score 3):

Нет, Java знать не надо. Код пишется на C# или JavaScript и потом компилируется в apk средствами Unity.

*by Алексей Шиманский*

Answer (score 0):

Java может понадобиться, если дело идет строго под Android, например, для плагинов. При создании маленького проекта она вряд-ли будет нужна.